# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, function, class, construct

I am getting this error:

> **( ! ) Notice:** Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\admin\paginator\Paginator.class.php on line 18.

**index page:**

```
<?php 
 require_once 'paginator/Paginator.class.php';

    $conn       = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'USER', 'PASS' );
     mysqli_select_db($link, "DB");
    $limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 25;
    $page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;


    $query      = "
SELECT utilizatori.id, utilizatori.utilizator, utilizatori.nume, utilizatori.rol_user 
AS ID, LOGIN, NUME, ROL 
FROM utilizatori
ORDER BY `utilizator` ASC";

    $Paginator  = new Paginator( $conn, $query );

    $results    = $Paginator->getData( $page, $limit );
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
        <tr>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['ID']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['NUME']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['LOGIN']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['ROL']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

**paginator.class.php:**

```
<?php

class Paginator {

        private $_conn;
        private $_limit;
        private $_page;
        private $_query;
        private $_total;


public function __construct( $conn, $query ) {

    $this->_conn = $conn;
    $this->_query = $query;

    $rs= $this->_conn->query( $this->_query );
    $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;
```

**Where the 18 line is:**

```
$this->_total = $rs->num_rows;
```

I checked everything but can't figure out where is the problem. Can anyone see where is the problem more than me, please?

Comment: I'm guessing that `$this->_conn->query()` isn't returning an object, based on the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is: `$rs` is not an object. And therefore it has neither properties nor methods, and you cannot treat it like an object like so: `$rs->num_rows`.

I assume (since `num_rows` is a property of `mysqli_result`) that your class's property `$this->_conn` is a `mysqli` object. If you look at the [documentation for `mysqli::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), you'll see that this method will return:

- `mysqli_result` object for `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN`
- `false` for failure
- `true` for other successful queries

In short, `$rs` is not a `mysqli_result` in your example. Your query is either not one of the above listed, or it is failing.

Perhaps you could make your code more robust with something like:

```
if (false === $rs) {
    // uh oh...
    throw new RuntimeException(
        sprintf('mysqli error! %s', $this->_conn->connect_error)
    );   
}
```

Please note that is not tested. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've answered not knowing you already explained it with a bit more detail. Deleting my answer :)

Comment: Hi. Well, I am not making that assumption because I don't know what your query is but it's certainly a possibility as it's one of the outcomes. If `$rs` is `false` the query failed, and the `connect_error` property should give you some meaningful information about what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Indeed, the query was the problem. Thank you very much!